# How can you read what type of Storage is 'this' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, storage, javascript-objects

I want to know how you can read what type of the Storage Object is "this"?
Let's say you got this function:

```
Storage.prototype.typeOf=function(){return this;}
```

Now you will see the data in sessionStorage or localStorage. But how to get this information in the JS code? I tried

```
Storage.prototype.typeOf=function(){
    var x=this;
    alert(this)
}
```

It returns just [object Storage] but this obviously isn't what I searched for.
I looked at the available methods of the Storage types but none returned the real type. Is there a method for getting this information?

Comment: Did you try `this === sessionStorage` and `this === localStorage` ?

Comment: I don't think there is any "correct" way to check this in JavaScript. There's only the single generic `Storage` type in JavaScript, which doesn't expose which underlying browser storage system it's connected to. You can of course check something like `this == sessionStorage`, but I don't think there's a better solution... but good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Storage objects **do not** expose any properties that can be used to distinguish whether they provide local or session storage. I just read through [the HTML storage specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html) and [much of the source code used to implement it](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/storage/) in Google Chrome to confirm this.

Your only option is to compare the identity of the Storage objects with their global definitions. You may want to just do this directly, and not bother wrapping it in a method.

```
if (someStorage === window.localStorage) {
  // ...
} else if (someStorage === window.sessionStorage) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there's only two types of Storage objects, you could just check for them explicitly.

```
Storage.prototype.typeOf = function() {
  if (this === window.localStorage) {
    return 'localStorage';
  }
  return 'sessionStorage';
};

console.log(localStorage.typeOf());   // 'localStorage'
console.log(sessionStorage.typeOf()); // 'sessionStorage'
```

Since each of these are just special instances of the Storage object, there's not a general way of determining what variable each instance has been assigned to.